# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" from Azure App Service API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, cors

I have a web API for backend and a Node.js app for frontend.

Both of them are hosted on Microsoft Azure App Services.

Both of them have run fine locally, but recently I have deployed them to Azure and I am getting the following error when trying to call the API from the Node.js app:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '[API endpoint URL]' from origin '[https://....azurewebsites.net]'
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource.
```

I have hidden the actual URL of the site but I can confirm it is identical to the one shown in the code below:

Here are the related parts of Startup.cs in the Web API:

```
...

readonly string[] origins = { "http://localhost:3000", "https:/....azurewebsites.net" };

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins(origins)
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Here is the endpoint that I am trying to access

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : BaseController
{
    ...
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string[]), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Organizations(string username)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I also think it's important to mention that I can access the endpoint locally even when not running the Node.js on port 3000, even though that's the only one that's listed in origins.

Comment: Might be worth checking the web API Azure logs for any errors. I’ve seen times when a site wasn’t working but all the browser reported was a CORS error

Comment: The error message is very clear.  There is a firewall (CORS policy) that is blocking your request because it contains the HTTP header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.  Talk to your MIS people to determine why the CORS policy is in place and if you can get your CORS permissions changed to allow code to run.

Comment: @jdweng The error message says there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present, which is what the code I showed is supposed to add. There are no firewalls in place on the App Service it was just set up

Comment: There must be a firewall if CORS is implemented.  A firewall is an application that blocks specific features.  It may be part of a Virus Checker application. A Firewall is a broader term than what you are calling a firewall.

Comment: @jdweng I have solved it, thanks for the point in the right direction. I will update the question title to reflect what the actual issue was and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that even though CORS was enabled in the application code, there is also a CORS page in the Azure portal where a list of origins must be added.

To find it just Search for 'CORS' in the Azure portal search bar and add the URL of the site that you would like to have access to your endpoints.